# Sum of matrix values, conditional, with infinite rows and columns

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have 2 sheets: "Planning" and "Utilization" ([example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g_cZzknU7GhyUjQMbC4dFStbJB1NBILjjwaQ-qYnhX8/edit?usp=sharing))

Planning: Employees assigned to projects for each week. Some projects are not fixed but need to be simulated (checkbox = true).

Utilization: Shows the utilization of each employee for each week. Only rows with:

a) no checkbox in Planning!A2:A
b) rows with checkbox checked
c) rows with project name in Planning!B2:B are to be considered.

I'd like to have a formula in Utilization!B2 that would calculate the sums for Utilization!B2:E4. With infinite rows and columns in Planning sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({Planning!A:H}; 
 "select Col3,sum(Col5),sum(Col6),sum(Col7),sum(Col8) 
  where not Col1 = FALSE 
    and Col3 is not null 
  group by Col3"; 0); 
 "offset 1"; 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({Planning!A:Z}; 
 "select Col3,"&
 TEXTJOIN(","; 1; IF(Planning!E1:1="";;"sum(Col"&COLUMN(E:Z)&")"))&" 
  where not Col1 = FALSE 
    and Col3 is not null  
  group by Col3"; 0); 
 "offset 1"; 0))
```

---

### FIX for 'get' error:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({Planning!A:D\Planning!E:Z*1}; 
 "select Col3,"&
 TEXTJOIN(","; 1; IF(Planning!E1:1="";;"sum(Col"&COLUMN(E:Z)&")"))&" 
  where not Col1 = FALSE 
    and Col3 is not null  
  group by Col3"; 0); 
 "offset 1"; 0))
```

Comment: thanx, but I need infinite columns and rows.

Comment: Hey player0. Thanx, works, but if I have only one entry for specific week, or if I have no entries for specific week, the formula breaks with error saying: "Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined". Any idea why?

Comment: @player0 The double query with "offset by 1" to get rid of labels?! My first time seeing that.  Very cool! Will have to try to remember to use it!

Comment: @MattKing yes indeed

Comment: @Mara try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({Planning!A:D\Planning!E:Z*1}; 
 "select Col3,"&
 TEXTJOIN(","; 1; IF(Planning!E1:1="";;"sum(Col"&COLUMN(E:Z)&")"))&" 
  where not Col1 = FALSE 
    and Col3 is not null  
  group by Col3"; 0); 
 "offset 1"; 0))`

Comment: @player0 , I have a follow up question. I've extended the above spreadsheet with 2 more sheets. Now I need to convert the percentages to hours (sheet "Potential"), based on the availability provided in sheet "Time". So for each day on x-axis, for each user in y-axis, there should be a lookup in "Time"-Sheet. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: I guess yes but not in an easy way. it would need to be totally dismantled, multiplied and the re-pivoted. I would need to test it further...

Answer (score 0):

For infinite rows and Columns, I like to use OFFSET()  so you might try this formula in A1 on a new tab.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(QUERY({Planning!A:D\N(OFFSET(Planning!E1;;;ROWS(Planning!E:E);COUNTA(Planning!E1:1)))};"select Col3, "&TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;"SUM(Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Planning!E1:1);1;5)&")")&" where Col2 is not null group by Col3";0);"offset 1";0)})
```

Comment: Mine is updated to reflect a new trick i learned from @player0